# mod_substitute errors out with "line too long"

Tags: apache

I am just trying to prepend and append a certain string to Apache responses matching certain filetypes. I thought `mod_substitute` would do the job, but it errors out all the time with: `AH01328: Line too long`.

This is what my directive looks like:

```
<Location "/src">
    AddType application/javascript .txt .tpl
    AddOutputFilter SUBSTITUTE tpl txt
    SubstituteMaxLineLength 10m
    Substitute "s/([\s\S]*)/export default `$1`/i"
</Location>
```

As you can see I also tried to up the limit on `SubstituteMaxLineLength`, but that seems to have no effects.

Any idea what I am doing wrong, or is there another option to solve this seemingly easy (well, apparently not so) task?

Comment: What version of apache are you using? SubstituteMaxLineLength is only available since version 2.4.11

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it resolved by using `mod_sed`, FYI:

```
# this converts the specified file type(s) into ES6 modules by
# wrapping the response in an "export", so it can be consumed 
# as a regular string, for example: "import string from 'text.txt'"
<Location "/src">
    AddType application/javascript .txt .tpl .vue
    AddOutputFilter Sed tpl vue txt
    OutputSed "1s/^/export default `/"
    OutputSed "$s/$/`/"
</Location>
```

Answer (score 1):

This helped me out, was getting random HTTP error messages regarding Network Timeout / Connection Closed before looking at error_log and seeing the error on mod_substitute.

I was able to add SubstituteMaxLineLength 10M  (with the capital M) and it worked for me.

Thanks!